# jQuery - element passed by reference only?

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var p = $('#hello');
    $(p).text('Yes');
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above resulting change the text inside `<p>` element, but is it reasonable?
Because it already 2 set of `<p>` element.

Comment: Sorry @SilverNight... What do you mean by "Because it already 2 set of element" ?

Comment: I think he ment 2 set of `<p>` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question (20% certainty) the answer is no, you do not need to wrap `p` as a JQuery object the second time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var p = $('#hello');
  p.text('Yes');
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hello').text('Yes');
});
```

will work fine.